# Problem regarding on HC-SR04 sonar with an additional stepper and SG90 servo motor

Tags: motor, servo, stepper, hc-sr04, project

I'm making a project based on HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor with a stepper motor and an SG90 servo motor. I have done some conditions for my stepper motor that is given below. Now I want to include my servo in it. When the distance goes below 10cm the servo rotates at 90 degrees (N.B. the stepper remain the same as it is) and when the distance is above 10cm then the servo comes back to 0 degree.

Please help me out to complete this.

Thanks.

```cpp
#include <Stepper.h>

// Define number of steps per rotation
const int stepsPerRevolution = 2048;

int rotationCW = 0;
int rotationCCW = 0;
int location = 1;

// Create stepper object called 'myStepper' note the pin order:
Stepper myStepper = Stepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);

const int trigPin = 2;
const int echoPin = 3;

// defines variables
long duration; // variable for the duration of sound wave travel
int distance; // variable for the distance measurement

void setup()
{
  myStepper.setSpeed(15); //Set the speed to 5 rpm

  Serial.begin(9600); // // Serial Communication is starting with 9600 of baudrate speed

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an OUTPUT
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an INPUT
}

void loop()
{
  // Clears the trigPin condition
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  // Sets the trigPin HIGH (ACTIVE) for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2; // Speed of sound wave divided by 2 (go and back)

  // Displays the distance on the Serial Monitor
  //Serial.print("Distance: ");
  //Serial.print(distance);
  //Serial.println(" cm");

  if (distance >= 20 && location == 1)
  {
    rotationCW = (.4 * stepsPerRevolution);
    myStepper.step(rotationCW);
    location = (2);
    delay(500);

    Serial.println ("Gate closed");
  }
  else if (distance <= 20 && location == 2)
  {
    rotationCCW = .4 * -stepsPerRevolution;
    myStepper.step(rotationCCW);
    location = 1;
    delay(500);

    Serial.println ("Gate opened");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem in doing this? I don't see any servo code.

Comment: There is no problem with this code. I just want to added an extra servo with it, and it will rotate 90 degrees when the distance measurement is under 10cm, and goes back to its initial stage (i.e. 0 degree) when the distance will be up to 10 cm.

Comment: But why are you not just doing this? Adding an if statement for 10cm and adding servo code (like in the examples that come with the Servo library). You can find many tutorials and examples online about how to use a servo with Arduino. Have you looked and tried them? What exactly didn't you understand? What exactly makes you problems here? We need to know that to provide a good answer. We won't just write the code for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried. I actually want to do a project that meets the following conditions. Those conditions are:
* When the distance is less than 20cm the stepper motor rotates clockwise (specific step) - gate open
* When the distance goes above 20cm, the stepper rotates counterclockwise (specified step) - gate closed

Comment: * When the distance goes below 10cm, a servo will rotate 90 degrees + as well as the stepper will fulfill its previous conditions.
* When the distance goes above 10cm, the servo fire will come to the previous position + the stepper will still keep the gate open because 20cm has been fixed before.

Comment: I don't understand how to create the loop, and which conditional loop is useful to fulfill those conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop"? Sounds just like ifstaments with distance < 10 (and the corresponding else statement), where you execute the `Servo.write()` in. Maybe it helps you to write that down. Imagine you are the program. What steps do you need to do in exactly which order to reach your goal. Each instruction needs to be one single action, like "set motor to 90°" or "if distance smaller than 10cm" or "rotate stepper Y steps". Check your own logic. When thats correct you can nearly directly translate each line into Arduino code